# How to create a matrix of density plots in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-science, data-analysis, data-cleaning

[image]Instead of creating different different plots for a data-frame, I want to create a matrix of density plots for a data frame where I can see all the columns in one plot. For creating it separately I am using below code. How can I get all the columns in one plot?

```
loan_amnt <- density(out_data$loan_amnt)
plot(loan_amnt, main="Loan Amount")
polygon(loan_amnt, col="red", border="blue")
```

[image]

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. Without data, we can only guess as to how exactly you'd need to set things up.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I upload a snap of my data. (I have low reputation since I just started with this account which is why I cannot upload a file or anything like that

Comment: If you read the link I posted, you'll see suggestions on using `dput` on a representative sample of your data, creating dummy data, or using a dataset that's commonly available with packages. We can't read data from a picture of a table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine `gather()` from library **dplyr**, and `facet_grid()` or `facet_wrap()` from **ggplot2**.

With `gather`, you regroup all your column names in one variable (values of these variables in a second variable) and then your build your plot with `ggplot` and by using `facet_wrap`, it will create one plot for each level of your variable with the column names.